# Can Jquery Validate be bypassed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have been a huge fan of Jquery validate since it came out but I am concerned that a user might find a way to bypass it (since it is all client-side) and pass bad data to my forms. I always do an exhaustive job of fields validation AFTER they get through validate, just to be sure. But does anyone know of specific ways to bypass validate that I might program against?

Comment: Any client-side validation can be bypassed simply by turning off JavaScript. If you want to be sure no bad data is saved on your server, check the data on the server-side.

Comment: Turning JS off entirely is a good way to bypass it, but you can't _program_ against that. You sort of can with `<noscript>`, but nothing beats validating server-side.

Comment: Something we've done at work is populate the action of the form after validation success javascript side. Prevents bots generally from submitting the form. It's very rare that users have it disabled these days. It's more certain functions that users have disabled, such as cookies or activex in more secure environments. The key thing: know your audience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to bypass javascript validation: turn off javascript in the browser.

Validating server side is not an "extra", it should be the base of your validation and be able to stand on it's own, with the client side validation being the "extra" part.

Comment: Also, if the `.validate()` rules of the form were referencing the names of form fields, one could simply change the `name` attribute of the field in the Dev Tools, and then submit to bypass that rule.

Answer (score 3):

> But does anyone know of specific ways to bypass validate that I might program against?

Anyone (with some programming background) could forge an HTTP request meaning that javascript validation could be bypassed easily. For this reason you should absolutely validate data on the server. You should never rely on javascript validation. There's even a simpler way to bypas it: disable javascript in your browser and you will be able to send whatever you want to the server. Use javascript validation only to improve user experience and save bandwidth but never as something that guarantees you valid data on the server. So if you had one single place to perform validation that would be the server.

Comment: Just to add on to this, skipping validation is even easier than that; people may cluelessly turn off JavaScript all together, so if the action attribute lines up, they'll skip validation unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

The great Problem of Client Side validation is the option "no Javascript".
You just have to Disable Javascript and all your validation functions would validate anything.
The Clientside validation ist just for prevent the User have to send the Form more then once to the server.

You have to check all your forms on the Server otherwise you are running in trouble with malfilled Forms.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sounds like my suspicions were correct and that robust server side eval is still required.